# load data into power BI from relative path

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to find a solution to load an external data file but from a relative path, so when someone else open my PBIX it will still work on his/her computer.

many thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Relative paths are ***not*** currently supported by Power BI.

[image: power bi does not support relative paths]

---

**To ease the pain**, you can create a variable that contains the path where the files are located, and use that variable to determine the path of each table. That way, you only have to change a single place (that variable) and all the tables will automatically point to the new location.

Create a Blank Query, give it a name (e.g. `dataFolderPath`) and type in the path where your files are (e.g. `C:\Users\augustoproiete\Desktop`)

[image: create Blank Query]

[image: type path for the files]

With the variable created, edit each of your tables in the `Advanced Editor` and concatenate your variable with the name of the file.

e.g. instead of `"C:\Users\augustoproiete\Desktop\data.xlsx"`, change it to `dataFolderPath & "\data.xlsx"`

[image]

---

You can also vote/watch this feature request to be notified when it gets implemented:

- [Support relative path to excel/csv sources](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9665565-support-relative-path-to-excel-csv-sources)

Comment: I honestly don't think they will ever implement it, because it would probably hurt their business model of selling PowerBI Publishing Server licenses. Because with relative paths pbix files would be sharable quite easily via Nextcloud etc...

Comment: I like this solution though it has a side-effect, which is that it prevents users from using the "Data source settings" dialog box, with its Browse button, to update the source file.  This leaves the Advanced Editor / Source settings in Power Query Editor as the only way to update the source file, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 8):

You can use also the "Parameters" function.
1. Create a new Parameter like "PathExcelFiles"
[Parameter_ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC2Li.jpg)

2. Edit your "Source" entry
   [SourceEntry_ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiIC2.jpg)

Done !

Comment: Works as long as you are using a path that does not vary between users. As long as the parameter is set as a static value, also the path will remain exactly the same.

Comment: Parameters can be set with an API call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible yet.

Please add your support for [this idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9665565-support-relative-path-to-excel-csv-sources) so the Microsoft Power BI team will be more likely to add this as a new feature.

Comment: Four years and 1000+ upvotes later, Microsoft still says the idea status "Needs Votes"?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't bear the fact that there is no possibility to use relative paths, but finally I had to...

So I tried to find a half-decent acceptable workaround.
Using Python-Script it is at least possible to get access to the users %HOME% directory.

```
let
    PySource = Python.Execute("from pathlib import Path#(lf)import pandas as pd#(lf)dataset = pd.DataFrame([[str(Path.home())]], columns = [1])"),
    homeDir = Text.Trim(Lines.ToText(PySource{[Name="dataset"]}[Value][1])),
    ...
```

The same should be possible with R-Script but didn't do it.

Anybody knows any better solution to get the %HOME% directory inside "Power" Query? I would be glad to have one.

Then I created two scripts inside my working directory **install.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
if exist "%HOME%\.pbiTemplatePath\filepath.txt" GOTO :ERROR

#This is are the key commands
mkdir "%HOME%\.pbiTemplatePath"
echo|set /p="%cd%" > "%HOME%\.pbiTemplatePath\filepath.txt"

GOTO :END

#Just a little message box
:ERROR
SET msgboxTitle=There is already another working directory installed.
SET /p msgboxBody=<"%HOME%\.pbiTemplatePath\filepath.txt"
SET tmpmsgbox=%temp%\~tmpmsgbox.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
WSCRIPT "%tmpmsgbox%"
:END
```

and **uninstall_all.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
if exist "%HOME%\.pbiTemplatePath\filepath.txt" RMDIR /S /Q "%HOME%\.pbiTemplatePath\"
```

So in "Power" BI I did this:

```
let
    PySource = Python.Execute("from pathlib import Path#(lf)import pandas as pd#(lf)dataset = pd.DataFrame([[str(Path.home())]], columns = [1])"),
    homeDir = Text.Trim(Lines.ToText(PySource{[Name="dataset"]}[Value][1])),
    workingDirFile = Text.Combine({homeDir, ".PbiTemplatePath\filepath.txt"} , "\"),
    workingDir = Text.Trim(Lines.ToText(Csv.Document(File.Contents(workingDirFile),[Delimiter=";", Columns=1, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])[Column1])),
    ...
```

Now if my git-repository (containing a "Power" BI-template-file and some config-files saying the template where to load the data from and the install/uninstall-scripts). Install has to be executed once and nobody has to copy and paste any path.

I'd be glad about any suggestion of improvement. It's not the solution Gotham deserves... Gotham deserves a better one.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by a few people, you can use a dataset parameter and reference that in your script.  What I haven't seen mentioned is that you can change these values using an API call:
[image: Sample Request]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kind of found a way to do that.

In my case I just want to change the Windows User name in the path of a file

```
let
    MainFolder = "C:\\Users\\",
    FolderData = "\\Downloads\\",
    File = "teste.xlsx",
    SheetName = "Plan1",
    Users = {"Mateo.Tesla", "Carl.Smith", "Bruna.Dias", "John.Mayer"}, // Add Here the different People will access your data
    Paths = List.Transform(Users, each Text.Combine({MainFolder, _, FolderCBERS, File}, "")),
    Lists = try List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Paths, each try Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(_), null, true) otherwise null)) otherwise null,
    TheTable = Lists{0},
    Sales_Sheet = TheTable{[Item=SheetName ,Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in
    Sales_Sheet
```